# Angularjs' function not firing when parameter is a 'view'

Tags: javascript, angularjs, model-view-controller

I am new to angularjs and I am creating a function. And the function has a parameter like this `{{sched.an_id}}`. But it doesn't work.  Here's my code:

```
$scope.sample = function(val){

    alert(val);

};
```

**HTML**

```
<table>
     <tr ng-repeat='sched in schedule'>
        <td>
             <a ng-click="sample({{sched.an_id}})"></a>
        </td>
     </tr>
</table>
```

In the html above, it doesnt alert the value of the `sample()`. I tried to inspect the element and it gives me the exact value `sample(23)`. I tried to remove the `{{sched.an_id}}` and replace `sample(123)` it works. What should I do?

Comment: Remove curly brackets, use `ng-click="sample(sched.an_id)"`

Comment: Thanks man, it works now! @Tushar

Comment: Please post your answer so that I can approved that it is the right answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are using `{{}}` inside `ng-click`

Try this

```
 <a ng-click="sample(sched.an_id)"></a>
```

Comment: its sir not maam :)

Comment: Ay, sorry sir maam!